# Set SQL DateTime to Empty/Nothing in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime, null

I have a `Date` column in SQL (of **DateTime** datatype). For a particular scenario, I need to show it as blank in my browser. I tried

```
Dim DOB As Nullable(Of Date) = Date.Now
Dim datestring As String = DOB.Value.ToString("d")
DOB = Nothing
```

But it gives me error saying `DateTime was not in a proper format`.

What is wrong here?

Comment: There's nothing in that code that will cause that error message.  You ought to have a closer look at the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try either of the following:

```vb
Dim datestring As String = IF(DOB Is Nothing,"", DOB.Value.ToString("d"))
```

or

```vb
Dim datestring As String = ""

If Not DoB Is Nothing Then
  datestring = DOB.Value.ToString("d")
End If
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work - I get `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store <> in AddedDate Column.  Expected type is DateTime.`

Comment: Did you try Convert.ToDateTime(datestring), Also I want know code fails at binding or assign from DOB to date string. Please confirm, Thanks

Comment: Try this Convert.ToDateTime(datestring). set a break point on date column assigning line, make sure above function convert the not null date value like this example {01/01/2014:11:20:00}- this value will be different at your end. good luck

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code would throw `DateTime was not in a proper format` is because *most likely* you don't do `Dim DOB As Nullable(Of Date) = Date.Now`. You get date from database and then go straight for value and value is null.

Let's say you have a Sql table with nullable date field and you read it using DataReader, you can do

```vb
Dim strDate as string
if IsDbNull(reader("myDateColumn")) then 
    strDate = String.empty
else
   DirectCast(reader("myDateColumn"), DateTime).ToString("your format here")
End If
```

A shorter version would be

```vb
Dim strDate as string = If(IsDbNull(reader("myDateColumn")), String.empty,
                           DirectCast(reader("myDateColumn"), DateTime).ToString("your format here"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.HasValue` property of `Nullable(Of..)` type for checkin if it is a Null
And `.Value` property to get object of `DateTime` for using `.ToString`

```vb
Dim dbdate As Nullable(Of DateTime) = DateTime.Now
Dim datetxt As String = If(dbdate.HasValue = true, 
                           dbdate.Value.ToString("d"), 
                           "")
```

Then I think `String.Format` will be better to use:

```vb
Dim dbdate As Nullable(Of DateTime) = DateTime.Now
Dim datetxt As String = String.Format("{0:d}", dbdate)
dbdate = Nothing
datetxt = String.Format("{0:d}", dbdate)
```

Comment: Plase, explain better your answer

Comment: @JoeTaras - add something more - was too busy when write answer, then forget about this. Thanks

Comment: Ok, when you're writing an answer you can't do anything ;) Have nice day